# UIStackView inside UIScrollView: how to center-align stack view / items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a `UIStackView` inside a `UIScrollView`, and when the width of all items in stack view is less then the width of the scroll view, I want to make the stack view (or the items) to be horizontally centered aligned with the scroll view.

I have the following constraints:

For scrollView: `H:|[stackView]|` and `V:|[stackView]|` (so stack view fits with scroll view)

But I can see the stack view seems to shrink to a minimum size that just enough for all its arranged subviews' intrinsic content size, and it's left aligned to the scroll view.

Is there anyway to make it horizontally-centred in the scroll view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

take a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html
search for 'Dynamic Stack View', it worked for me